# How to create a htaccess file in WordPress?

Tags: php

I went to my WordPress root folder to search for a .htaccess file but it was not there. Can I create one of my own .htaccess file and put it there so I can do the modifications in it?

Please guide me.

Thank you.

Comment: Lazy. http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess Someone with as much rep as you should know better.

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/why-you-cant-find-htaccess-file-on-your-wordpress-site/

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new text file on your computer and name it .htaccess
2. Save it, it will be named ".htaccess.txt"
3. Remove the .txt, making it simply ".htaccess", and add anything you want to it.
4. Upload the file into your root folder.
5. Profit

Comment: Step 2 should be to add the following text to the file:
http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess